# MimeKit Exits Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mimekit

Im attempting to us MimeKit to retrieve a list of unread emails on a IMAP server

Here is my code

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    client.Connect("mail.zebracars.co.uk", 993, true);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate("email@email.co.uk", "12345");

    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    SearchQuery query;
    query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains("test");

    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query))
    {
        var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);

        List<String> formEmails = null;
        List<DateTime> messageDate = null;
        formEmails.Add(message.TextBody);
        messageDate.Add(message.Date.LocalDateTime);
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The method exists unexpectedly without any error messages while running this line

```
var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
```

The "message" variable is never populated

However the inbox variable is populated (only after the getmessage call) and contains a results view with all the messages from the email server.

This assures me that the connection information is valid. However without an error message to go off I'm stuck. The MimeKit also has a Async method which I have called along with await, in case the results needed time to return.

UPDATE
Below is the imap.log file produced from the above

```
Connected to imaps://mail.server.co.uk:993/
S: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE QUOTA SORT SORT=DISPLAY AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=DIGEST-MD5] Dovecot ready.
C: A00000000 AUTHENTICATE 
S: A00000000 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE QUOTA SORT SORT=DISPLAY QUOTA] Logged in
C: A00000001 NAMESPACE
S: * NAMESPACE (("" ".")) NIL NIL
S: A00000001 OK Namespace completed.
C: A00000002 LIST "" "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"
S: A00000002 OK List completed.
C: A00000003 LIST (SPECIAL-USE) "" "*"
S: * LIST (\Sent) "." "Sent"
S: * LIST (\Drafts) "." "Drafts"
S: * LIST (\Trash) "." "Trash"
S: A00000003 OK List completed.
C: A00000004 EXAMINE INBOX (CONDSTORE)
S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Read-only mailbox.
S: * 2 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UNSEEN 1] First unseen.
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1506447851] UIDs valid
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 3] Predicted next UID
S: * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 2] Highest
S: A00000004 OK [READ-ONLY] Select completed.
C: A00000005 UID SEARCH RETURN () SUBJECT test
S: * ESEARCH (TAG "A00000005") UID ALL 1:2
S: A00000005 OK Search completed (0.011 secs).
C: A00000006 UID FETCH 1 (BODY.PEEK[])
S: * 1 FETCH (UID 1 BODY[] {5087}
S: Return-path: <email@email.com>
S: Envelope-to: email@email.com
S: Delivery-date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 18:44:11 +0100
S: Received: from mail by mail114.server.co.uk with spamvirus-scanned (Exim 4.87)
S:  id 1dwttz-000381-Ox
S:  for email@email.com; Tue, 26 Sep 2017 18:44:11 +0100
S: X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on
S:  mail114.server.co.uk
S: X-Spam-Level: 
S: X-Spam-Status: No, score=0.4 required=5.0 tests=DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,
S:  DKIM_VALID_AU,FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_SORBS_SPAM shortcircuit=no
S:  autolearn=disabled version=3.3.1
S: Received: from mail-wr0-f177.google.com ([209.85.128.177])
S:  by mail114.server.co.uk with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:128)
S:  (Exim 4.87)
S:  id 1dwttz-00037Z-NC
S:  for email@email.com; Tue, 26 Sep 2017 18:44:11 +0100
S: Received: by mail-wr0-f177.google.com with SMTP id a43so13382310wrc.0
S:         for <email@email.com>; Tue, 26 Sep 2017 10:44:11 -0700 (PDT)
S: DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
S:         d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
S:         h=message-id:mime-version:to:from:subject:date:importance;
S:         bh=kdGDYwbddyE9ukcooED6VhTd4ZHq47tHQNNwiXGeubc=;
S:         b=JR7erLZLcvTxAmFUkUUBLgPsaSWUicupakG44I3wGcBkOEij2pC/LjoHmBfXLHA/l/
S:          xhBxZ4YLgg/74YdBsGIusxAWAwVLUcqmXCQhG2xI8GLx2j8Kup/ttyV0RDb7+vYZjzOC
S:          PTOCfYsbE7zvx0dW5V64xoc0WSbXRpjAKQdzqCfnLZnjs7afdu19qTs/jOKQU5+aJ+H0
S:          lbEsiMKNlhxmB+n4KlJlE9Q3kiY7csZ3YXGXI0IdEX9LySmnM0Q90opOC1BSp7O/QqM2
S:          t0XrJj7hir/JjbncVgs/KEr6jilsVlzXurKoTqZBkH9/igzW0yDeDO9oHC/M/PLxRdxw
S:          zr4Q==
S: X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
S:         d=1e100.net; s=20161325;
S:         h=x-gm-message-state:message-id:mime-version:to:from:subject:date
S:          :importance;
S:         bh=kdGDYwbddyE9ukcooED6VhTd4ZHq47tHQNNwiXGeubc=;
S:         b=bgSxyHECPJ35wgGoir+gJV0RIvUhk3hX2RIR9sH+GgosiEsPoSisf6gst9d1P6Vj1D
S:          kXMfOD6A1KXukyLNga9gJ9T4X3IHUJSHYhWK5YLzYKpt9bQffTTtmb72Zg4xSpW0wAVp
S:          aQ9UFZ/6E6YPEzeIoRqKHZE9QqCEC/NUTzOaj3gaWRIjuyM2ROSoOGjLPIDYD1zyngM3
S:          R2IPtexajKUf2Zj9KiqlUaFh0GW1AEqvV6EEO1KxU+k8AZV7wzyjihgQfbolFSxtYyQU
S:          N9hYbSmfekCeHQEnl54JgWuCqpT/p9ZL0223ba2UA57iBQ8TwfagTDo8qNruCNsVB29m
S:          V+eA==
S: X-Gm-Message-State: AHPjjUgYzu3L/nWcZ6+sUeQCtxUXfrA48l09I7OK5vrVcpXZbcfAQ8E4
S:  gER31TV8XOOI/KWPcFBtucTfMaCR
S: X-Google-Smtp-Source: AOwi7QDf8N/N6/6ChsfOGgDRBdtq6KNFTU59ZkBCloLolhIL7pzvxKWWN8oGvpyRa1NuCPNx3rJCxA==
S: X-Received: by 10.223.176.13 with SMTP id f13mr8600118wra.220.1506447851022;
S:         Tue, 26 Sep 2017 10:44:11 -0700 (PDT)
S: Received: from ?IPv6:::ffff:192.168.0.103? (cpc81910-lon-2-0-cust393.1-1.cable.virginm.net. [83.11.115.178])
S:         by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id k18sm2616400wmd.22.2017.09.26.10.44.09
S:         for <crm@zebracars.co.uk>
S:         (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AER128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
S:         Tue, 26 Sep 2017 10:44:10 -0700 (PDT)
S: Message-ID: <59ca91ea.12591c0a.ed925.edb7@mx.google.com>
S: MIME-Version: 1.0
S: To: "" <>
S: From:  <>t: test
S: Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 18:44:10 +0100
S: Importance: normal
S: X-Priority: 3
S: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
S:  boundary="_CE2445A7-C117-4ED4-B205-4C40AD703C0C_"
S: 
S: --_CE2445A7-C117-4ED4-B205-4C40AD703C0C_
S: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
S: Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
S: 
S: test
S: 
S: Sent from Mail for Windows 10
S: 
S: 
S: --_CE2445A7-C117-4ED4-B205-4C40AD703C0C_
S: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
S: Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
S: 
S: <html xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w=3D"urn:sc=
S: hemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/of=
S: fice/2004/12/omml" xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta ht=
S: tp-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"><meta name=
S: =3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
S: /* Font Definitions */
S: @font-face
S:  {font-family:"Cambria Math";
S:  panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
S: @font-face
S:  {font-family:Calibri;
S:  panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
S: /* Style Definitions */
S: p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
S:  {margin:0cm;
S:  margin-bottom:.0001pt;
S:  font-size:11.0pt;
S:  font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
S: a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
S:  {mso-style-priority:99;
S:  color:blue;
S:  text-decoration:underline;}
S: a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
S:  {mso-style-priority:99;
S:  color:#954F72;
S:  text-decoration:underline;}
S: .MsoChpDefault
S:  {mso-style-type:export-only;}
S: @page WordSection1
S:  {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
S:  margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
S: div.WordSection1
S:  {page:WordSection1;}
S: --></style></head><body lang=3DEN-GB link=3Dblue vlink=3D"#954F72"><div cla=
S: ss=3DWordSection1><p class=3DMsoNormal>test</p><p class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&n=
S: bsp;</o:p></p><p class=3DMsoNormal>Sent from <a href=3D"https://go.microsof=
S: t.com/fwlink/?LinkId=3D550986">Mail</a> for Windows 10</p><p class=3DMsoNor=
S: mal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>=
S: 
S: --_CE2445A7-C117-4ED4-B205-4C40AD703C0C_--
S: 
S: )
S: A00000006 OK Fetch completed.
```

stack trace is as follows

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ZebraCRM.Web.Controllers.LeadsController.GetEmail() in C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ZebraCRM\ZebraCRM.Web\Controllers\LeadsController.cs:line 186
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Follow the directions in MailKit's [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) to get a protocol log and post that in your question (minus any authentication data).

Comment: Hi, i have updated the the question with the additional log file. Thanks

Comment: Is an exception thrown? If so, what exception? I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: i originally used this as a extension method and no error message, i have since moved it to the actionand receive  a nulll reference exception on the var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid); on closer inspection the uid variable is never populated

Comment: Can you get me a full StackTrace of the exception you are getting? The UID is a struct so it is always populated.

Comment: i have added the stack trace to the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting a `NullReferenceException` is that you are initializing `formEmails` to `null` instead of `new List<string> ()` and then trying to add items to a null list.

Likewise, you'll need to initialize `messageDate` to `new List<DateTime> ()` instead of `null` as well.

Comment: i have made the change and initialized the correct types. The routeen now progresses past the GetMessage call however the message variable is still empty and therefore the properties are not accessible

Comment: The message can't be empty.

Comment: i have changed TextBody to HtmlBody and its the same. I have set breakpoints on the fromemails.add() and it doesn't stop. I have added a watch to the message variable and it is never initialized

Comment: Are you getting an exception now?

Comment: If you aren't getting an exception, then by definition the message must be getting initialized to non-null which means it isn't empty and it *must* be getting to the add() method invocations. If your debugger isn't stopping there, then it's broken somehow which also makes me doubt it when it says that `message` isn't getting initialized.

Comment: Try splitting this method out into a simple Console program in Visual Studio and step through it in a debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: i cant send you the additional stack trace as ive reached the chr limit for the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155430/discussion-between-jstedfast-and-powerman2015).